# Cumulative Sum over Last 12 Months - Missing Dates?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm running a cumulative sum over the last 12 months, using OVER clause on SQL. So far, so good, but just noticed that I have missing dates in my table. So, my calculation should summing over the previous 12 calendar months whether there are spends in those months or not.
Please, refer below my current code:

```
SELECT  *,
         SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date_Month ROWS BETWEEN 12 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS TwelveMoTtl
         FROM ( 
    SELECT DISTINCT
        CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, TransactionDt), 0) AS DATE)   AS Date_Month,
        ID,
        SUM(Amount) AS Amount
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY
        ID,
        CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, TransactionDt), 0) AS DATE)
```

For some IDs, there's missing dates in MyTable. So, I'm using a basic LEFT JOIN with a DimCalendar table in order to populated the final results with those missing dates.

In below results, see two highlighted examples in yellow, the cumulative calculation (TwelveMoTtl) and the expected result with red font.

[image]

Any suggestions how could I do it?

Comment: It is not really clear what you want. Please provide sample data and expected results as tabular text to enhance your question.

Comment: first step would be this: SUM(ISNULL(Amount,0))

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the dates and fill in the missing rows.  Then your code works:

```
WITH dates as (
      SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, EOMONTH(MIN(TransactionDt), -1)) as dte,
             MAX(TransactionDt) as maxdte
      FROM mytable t
      UNION ALL
      SELECDT DATEADD(month, 1, dte), maxdte
      FROM dates
      WHERE dte < maxdte
     )
SELECT d.dte, SUM(AMOUNT) as amount,
       SUM(SUM(Amount)) OVER (ORDER BY d.dte ROWS BETWEEN 12 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)FROM dates d LEFT JOIN
FROM dates JOIN
     MyTable t
     ON t.TransactionDt >= d.dte AND
        t.TransactionDt < DATEADD(month, 1, d.dte)
GROUP BY d.dte
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. But, if I need another column from MyTable, the column "ID", where should I put it, on the CTE?

Comment: @RafaelFloridoPereira . . . (1) You have no `id` in your question so that should be a new question if you can't figure it out.  (2) I don't see how an `id` would fit in to the final result.  (3) You can just add it to the two selects for `dates` or pull it when you `join` to `MyTable`.